# Buzzing Noise and error 01 canon camera

Tags: lens, canon

Hi I have a canon rebel T3 have a canon 75-300 mm lens. When i lock the lens in and turn on it starts to make a buzzing noise and I get error 01 when I try to take a picture. I try to take pictures when its not completely locked in and it do take pictures. Not the best pictures actually very poor ones. Would like to know how I can get fix this before y next lot of pictures.

Comment: There have been multiple Canon EF 75-300mm lens models sold over the past three decades. Which *specific* lens model do you have? (i.e. EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 IS USM, EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6, EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 USM, EF 75-300mm II or III (with or without USM focusing), etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> Hi I have a canon rebel T3 have a canon 75-300 mm lens. When i lock
> the lens in and turn on it starts to make a buzzing noise and I get
> error 01 when I try to take a picture.

The buzzing noise sounds ominous, unless your 75-300 is an IS version of that lens (Canon made *numerous* versions of the 75-300 [I, II, and III versions, both with and without USM and/or IS]).

Err01 indicates that there's an electronic miscommunication between the camera body and the lens.  Your lens may be broken; it may have broken/dirty contacts. Your camera mount may have had its electronic contacts broken or obstructed with dirt.

Shooting with the lens partially mounted means the camera thinks it's shooting without a lens mounted, and it cannot control any of the lens's settings (i.e., no aperture or focus adjustments can happen).

> I try to take pictures when its
> not completely locked in and it do take pictures. Not the best
> pictures actually very poor ones.

Well, it can't focus or adjust the aperture, and at 300mm, your shutter speed likely needs to be at or above 1/500s to mitigate for camera shake blur form handholding.

> Would like to know how I can get fix this before [my] next lot of pictures.

You might not be able to. But I would visually inspect the camera mount's electrical contacts and the gold contacts on the back of the lens to make sure nothing's broken or dirty. If they are dirty, you want to clean them very carefully, either with a soft pencil eraser or some type of volatile no-residue cleaner with something that will not scratch (some folks just use sensor cleaning gear), or no-contact (bulb blower).

If you have access to another lens, you may want to try it on the camera body to determine if it's the lens or the camera that's the issue.

Comment: The only EF 75-300mm lens made by Canon that had IS is a completely different lens design with a completely different optical formula and mechanical design from all of the other 75-100mm lenses, which all have the same or very similar optical formulae. The EF 75-300mm IS was introduced way back in 1995 and replaced by the first EF 70-300mm IS in 2005, which had a similar optical formula to the 75-300mm IS. It was replaced by the EF 70-300mm IS II in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the manual on the Canon website. It has a section on error codes. It says:

> If there is a problem with the camera, an error message will appear.
> Follow the on-screen instructions.
>
> Error No. 01
> Communications between the camera and lens is faulty. Clean the lens contacts.
> Clean the electrical contacts on the camera and lens and use a Canon lens.

You'll find some more relevant information in this question:
[How to clean contacts on my canon 1100d DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/36184)